# MVC Modify Object between View and Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am posting a text block from a View to a Controller for a message system.

Is there any way to catch the message before it hits the Controller, modify it in some way (Such as remove any unwanted stuff *like HTML elements*), and then let the Controller receives it?

The aim is to stop the `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected` without having to modify validation settings.

**Edit:** I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't involve any Ajax or Client Side modification - I want it to be bulletproof, and not rely on the person having JS enabled.

Comment: best way is to post data with ajax...this warning which is coming in your case comes.. when we try to post html tags from view to controller

Comment: I was really hoping to stay away from any JS answer

Comment: Well without client side modification(ajax)..in my opinion you can't do that but you can use attributes like [AllowHtml] or [ValidateInput(false)] to prevent the warning which is coming in your case.

Comment: @Kartikeya `[AllowHtml]` does sort out the issue - thanks! Although I won't be able to mark it as the answer because it technically doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The aim of the A `potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected` message is not to allow dangerous injection in your code.

You can either allow all HTML or reject dangerous injection or encode values before saving.

If you choose to allow all HTML use `[AllowHtml]` helper

--OR--

If you want to prevent dangerous script injection use,

```
[ValidateInput(true)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(FormCollection collection) 
{

}
```

--OR--

Use a custom attribute to encode all values using the Server.HtmlEncode method

Ex: `Server.HtmlEncode("<script>unsafe</script>");` 
before saving .